# ZF2 Validation - Field required if another element is not empty

Tags: zend-framework2

I've had experience with making custom validation in Zend Framework 2 (using version 2.0.5 at present). I'm interested in creating a change password section in an "edit profile" form. What I want to be able to do, is have 3 fields:

- Current Password,
- New Password,
- Confirm New Password.

Then I want to validate as follows:

- If a new password is set, current password must also be set (and authenticated), and confirm new password should match new password.
- If a current password is set, the new password and confirm new password must also be required.
- If none are set, allow the edit of the rest of the profile, so continue validation.

I think you can get the gist of what I'm after, I'm looking for a reusable way to do this using Zend Framework 2. Ideally, creating a custom validator so that the forms can be reused, thought I suspect a factory approach may be better. Anything so I don't have to check it in the controller/service layer and repeat myself wherever I want to use this.

Kind Regards,

ise

Answer (score -2):

You could add a custom filter, but I think this could also be done using validation groups and separately validate groups of inputs.

you could add the password fields to a separate group and only validate that group if the main password is not empty.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#validation-groups-for-fieldsets-and-collection